# Spring app - run method on end of transaction?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I wondering it is possible to configure spring in way to fire particular method on end transaction?

For example I have service class with method

```
@Service
public class service implements IService
{
    @Resource
    private EntityDao entityDao;

    @Resource
    private SomeService someService;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void doThings()
    {
       entityDao.doSmthOnDb();
       someService.thisMethodFiresOnEndOfTransaction();
    }

}
```

and second service class

```
@Service
public class secondService implements ISecondService
{
  @Resource
  private IService service;

  @Transactional
  @Override
  public void method()
  {
  service.doThings();
  /*
  some other code that can break transaction
  */
  }
}
```

so if I call `secondService.method()` I want that `someService.thisMethodFiresOnEndOfTransaction()` will be fire only if transaction end successfully.

Is it possible in spring?

Comment: Create another service (non-transactional) which calls the transactional service, put a try/catch around that call. If all goes well (i.e. no exception) call your methods, else throw exception or whatever you want to do with it.  Not really spring related imho.

Comment: @M.Deinum my point is to hook up this code once, becouse "service.doThings()" it's called in dozen other services.

Comment: And why would you need to do this more then once? Replace the calls to `service.doThings()` with `newService.doThings()`. You can of course use AOP but that would be a bit like using a canon to kill a fly. Or create a new service, and call that from `service.doThings` and that new service does the transactional stuff.

Comment: Assume service.doThings() change status on object based on some bisnes logic. So I must call it every time when I edited this object. It happens in different services. When status is change I send notifications to users, it's -> someService.thisMethodFiresOnEndOfTransaction() I can't send notification before transaction end couse I don't have certainty that will be success end.

Comment: As stated, move the transactional logic to a different service, which you call from the `service.doThings`. The only thing that needs to change is the `service.doThings` implementation. Calling services remain unchanged...

Comment: I don't get it your point. Services that calls service.doThings do diffferent things (also need transaction). I can't reverse worflow and call other methods from service.doThings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if it's good idea to delegate this to spring when you can add new bean as indirection layer between those services and delegate this thing to it.

But if you really don't have choice or want to do it with Spring, you can specify your own `PlatformTransactionManager`, which will delegate all calls to default manager, but also intercepts successful `commit()` calls.
Example:

```
public class MyTransactionalManager implements PlatformTransactionManager {
// ... implementation via delegation skipped here
    @Override
    public void commit(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {
        defaultManager.commit(status);
        // You might want to check status.isRollbackOnly() here
        someService.thisMethodFiresOnEndOfTransaction();
}
```

Now you can either replace default transaction manager in your application (then ::thisMethodFiresOnEndOfTransaction will be called after ***each*** transaction) or add it in context with some qualifier, then you should write something like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional(value = "myManager", rollbackFor = ...)  
public void method()
```

(And in the end of the answer I still think this is flawed approach and implementing it via just another bean is far better)

Comment: my point is to hook up this code once, becouse "service.doThings()" it's called in dozen other services. Solution with additional layer means a lot of work with adding it.

Comment: So using custom transactional manager instead of default is your choice, isn't it?

Comment: Yest it is :) Before your I didn't know about this solustion :)

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, if you want to run a method at the end of a transaction, you can utilize the @Transactional annotation along with the TransactionSynchronizationManager class to register after-commit hooks

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Transactional
  public void myTransactionalMethod() {
    // Your transactional code here...

    // Register after-commit hook
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCommit() {
            runAfterTransaction();
        }
    });
  }

  public void runAfterTransaction() {
    // Your after-commit logic here...
    System.out.println("This method runs after the transaction is successfully committed!");
  }
}
```